# Change the color of a card view dynamically if it's started processing

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm making an app for employees who are assigned multiple tasks at a time. I'm using CardView inside Fragment. The CardViews have the details about the task.   There is a different CardView for every task. Now I want to change the background color of the CardView which is currentely on process, and the rest a different color. And after completing the task the color goes back.

Comment: Please post some code of what you have already tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your card in XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

  android:id="@+id/card_view">
  card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/xml_defined_color"

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

// get your card view

```
CardView card = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);
```

// set CardView background color dynamically in your desired condition

```
card.cardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff282828"));
```